# Oracle 11g Trigger Error - ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I am still very new to Oracle SQL (specifically Oracle 11g SQL). I am trying to write a trigger but I cannot seem to get around all of the errors. Currently when I try to execute the SQL listed below, I get this error:

```
Error at line 12: PL/SQL: ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected

1. CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER course_assignment_trigger
2. AFTER INSERT ON Assign FOR EACH ROW
3. DECLARE
```

This is the SQL I have:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER course_assignment_trigger
AFTER INSERT ON Assign FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
   tooManyCourses EXCEPTION;
   notQualified EXCEPTION;
   assignedBeforeQualified EXCEPTION;
   assignedCourseCount int;
   qualifiedRowCount int;
   PRAGMA EXCEPTION_INIT( tooManyCourses, -20001 );
   PRAGMA EXCEPTION_INIT( notQualified, -20001 );
   PRAGMA EXCEPTION_INIT( assignedBeforeQualified, -20001 );


BEGIN
   SELECT assignedCourseCount = COUNT(*) FROM Assign where Fid = :new.Fid;
   IF assignedCourseCount  >= 3
   THEN
       RAISE tooManyCourses;
   END IF;

   SELECT qualifiedRowCount = COUNT(*) FROM Qualify where Fid = :new.Fid and Cid = :new.Cid;
   IF qualifiedRowCount = 0
   THEN
       RAISE notQualified;
   END IF;

   IF(:new.assignDate < (select qualifyDate from Qualify where Fid = :new.Fid and Cid = :new.Cid))
   THEN
       RAISE unacceptedDateOfQualification;
   END IF;

EXCEPTION
   WHEN tooManyCourses THEN
       DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Cannot assign faculty to more than 3 courses.');

   WHEN notQualified THEN
       DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Faculty is not qualified to teach the course.');

   WHEN assignedBeforeQualified THEN
       DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Date of qualification must be before date of assignment.');

END;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are almost there.

The syntax is:

```sql
SELECT column_identifier
INTO   plsql_variable
FROM   table
-- ...
```

And you `RAISE unacceptedDateOfQualification` when you declared the exception as `assignedBeforeQualified` and need to give each exception a different error number. However, you almost certainly don't want to raise custom exceptions and catch them in the same trigger and output to the console as it won't prevent the `INSERT` from occurring; you want to `RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR` with your custom error message and want to do it `BEFORE INSERT`.

Like this:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER course_assignment_trigger
BEFORE INSERT ON Assign FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
   assignedCourseCount int;
   qualifiedRowCount int;
   qualifyDt DATE;
BEGIN
   SELECT COUNT(*)
   INTO   assignedCourseCount
   FROM   Assign
   where Fid = :new.Fid;
   
   IF assignedCourseCount  >= 3
   THEN
       RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR( -20001, 'Cannot assign faculty to more than 3 courses.');
   END IF;

   SELECT COUNT(*)
   INTO   qualifiedRowCount
   FROM   Qualify
   where  Fid = :new.Fid
   and    Cid = :new.Cid;

   IF qualifiedRowCount = 0
   THEN
       RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR( -20002, 'Faculty is not qualified to teach the course.');
   END IF;

   select MIN(qualifyDate)
   INTO   qualifyDt
   from   Qualify
   where  Fid = :new.Fid
   and    Cid = :new.Cid;
   
   IF :new.assignDate < qualifyDt
   THEN
       RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR( -20003, 'Date of qualification must be before date of assignment.' );
   END IF;
END;
/
```

If you have the tables:

```sql
CREATE TABLE assign (
  FID number,
  CID number,
  assignDate DATE
);

CREATE TABLE qualify (
  FID number,
  CID number,
  qualifyDate DATE
);
```

And then:

```sql
INSERT INTO assign VALUES ( 1, 1, DATE '2020-01-01' );
```

Raises the exception:

```
ORA-20002: Faculty is not qualified to teach the course.
ORA-06512: at "FIDDLE_BLJCMOGDEOXTZOEWHDDA.COURSE_ASSIGNMENT_TRIGGER", line 24
ORA-04088: error during execution of trigger 'FIDDLE_BLJCMOGDEOXTZOEWHDDA.COURSE_ASSIGNMENT_TRIGGER'
```

Then:

```sql
INSERT INTO qualify VALUES ( 1, 1, DATE '2020-01-01' );
INSERT INTO assign VALUES ( 1, 1, DATE '2020-01-01' );
```

Works but:

```sql
INSERT INTO assign VALUES ( 1, 1, DATE '2019-01-01' );
```

Raises the exception:

```
ORA-20003: Date of qualification must be before date of assignment.
ORA-06512: at "FIDDLE_BLJCMOGDEOXTZOEWHDDA.COURSE_ASSIGNMENT_TRIGGER", line 35
ORA-04088: error during execution of trigger 'FIDDLE_BLJCMOGDEOXTZOEWHDDA.COURSE_ASSIGNMENT_TRIGGER'
```

and:

```sql
INSERT INTO assign VALUES ( 1, 1, DATE '2020-01-01' );
INSERT INTO assign VALUES ( 1, 1, DATE '2020-01-01' );
INSERT INTO assign VALUES ( 1, 1, DATE '2020-01-01' );
```

Inserts the 2nd and 3rd copy of the row but the 4th copy raises the exception:

```
ORA-20001: Cannot assign faculty to more than 3 courses.
ORA-06512: at "FIDDLE_BLJCMOGDEOXTZOEWHDDA.COURSE_ASSIGNMENT_TRIGGER", line 13
ORA-04088: error during execution of trigger 'FIDDLE_BLJCMOGDEOXTZOEWHDDA.COURSE_ASSIGNMENT_TRIGGER'
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=f57f6be84fabc1557df2530872dd3a08)*

Comment: That did exactly what I needed it to! Thank you so much! I certainly wasn't aware about how raising a custom exception won't prevent the insert (among the other syntax corrections you included in your answer). Thanks again!

Comment: @ChapterSevenSeeds Raising any exception would prevent the insert if it is raised `BEFORE INSERT` (and not `AFTER INSERT`) but your problem was that you were catching the exception and trying to output to the console. The user won't see the output to the console and the exception won't be propagated (as you've caught and handled it) so won't stop anything. You need to raise the exception and not catch it.

Comment: Yeah I noticed that too. I changed it to 'AFTER INSERT' since that was the intended functionality.  Also, thanks for the further explanation on exceptions. I'm surprised I didn't realize that it is just like any other language with exception handling (throw it and don't catch it to display a system generated error message). Oh the woes of learning college homework material from the internet in a single afternoon.

Comment: @ChapterSevenSeeds Have you tested it with `AFTER INSERT`? It raises `ORA-04091: table FIDDLE_XHTVJTOGXWAVJLHUHUDM.ASSIGN is mutating, trigger/function may not see it` on every insert [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=0a25fcbc5a0bb488360d3bbd496b21df).

Comment: Yeah and that was why I changed it. The rows weren't being inserted (which was what I originally wanted) but that error message seemed unseemly. Once again, basically all of the declaration of the trigger was directly from the internet without much context. I was so dead set on fixing the body that I didn't see the glaring 'AFTER INSERT' there.